# If you had to write the command `\lhd` in English, what would it say?

Tags: macros, symbols, tex-history

In **LaTeX** I sometimes see the command `\lhd`.

It ends up looking like a Greek letter delta.

> ## ⊲

Usually, **LaTeX** commands are acronyms, initialisms, or abbreviations.

What is the fully spelled out English phrase for `\lhd`.

For example, `\dfrac` is an abbreviation of the English phrase `display fraction`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

that is from `latexsym`: `l` is "left" there are `r` "right" variants

```
%
%    The commands defined by the \texttt{latexsym} package are:
%    \begin{quote}\raggedright
%    |\mho|~$\mho$ \quad
%    |\Join|~$\Join$ \quad
%    |\Box|~$\Box$ \quad
%    |\Diamond|~$\Diamond$ \quad
%    |\leadsto|~$\leadsto$ \quad
%    |\sqsubset|~$\sqsubset$ \quad
%    |\sqsupset|~$\sqsupset$ \quad
%    |\lhd|~$\lhd$ \quad
%    |\unlhd|~$\unlhd$ \quad
%    |\rhd|~$\rhd$ \quad
%    |\unrhd|~$\unrhd$
%    \end{quote}
```

The font source says

```
% This character uses the rightward arrow arrowhead
% The width is the same as that of the regular arrow
% An extension character can be added for longer squiggles


cmchar "LASY \lhd triangle";
```

so `hd` is short for (arrow) HeaD

Answer (score 3):

`\lhd` stands for left-hand diamond according to: [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/lhd.htm)

Comment: but diamonds are 4-sided

Comment: Yes and this is just the left hand side of a diamond and therefore only a triangle... I did not make this up and would have chosen a different name. But that seems to be it...

Comment: "diamond" is not mentioned in Leslie Lamport's comments in the source, he describes these as arrow heads.

Comment: @mrCarnivore Can you link to the source of this theory?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/lhd.htm

Comment: @mrCarnivore Thanks for adding the link! Personally I would trust the comments in the source more than that site.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: You surely are right. I did not look into the source... It sounded not too bad, though...

Answer (score 0):

For people who want a short answer:

> The command `\lhd` migh be `\leftarrowhead` if it were written out in full English.

If you want to understand ***why*** "left arrow head" is the answer, then please read the excellent answer written by [David  Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle).